# No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/owaspzap/report.xml

Tags: azure, handlebars.js, owasp, zap

I have an azure release pipeline for OWASP ZAP with Handlebars which appears to run but no report is being created.
The agent used is ubuntu-latest
After the run we see this

[image]

Here we have the yaml details

Install Docker

```
steps:
- task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Docker'
```

Run ZAP Scan

```
steps:
- task: CSE-DevOps.zap-scanner.custom-build-release-task.owaspzap@1
  displayName: 'Run ZAP Scan'
  inputs:
    scantype: targetedScan
    url: '$(targetUrl)'
    port: 443
  continueOnError: true
```

Install Handlebars

```
steps:
- bash: |
   sudo npm install -g handlebars-cmd
   cat <<EOF > owaspzap/nunit-template.hbs
   {{#each site}}
    <test-run id="2" name="Owasp test" start-time="{$generatedDateTime}">
        <test-suite id="{{@index}}" type="Assembly" name="{{[@name]}}" result="Failed" failed="{{alerts.length}}">
            <attachments>
                <attachment>
                    <filePath>owaspzap/report.xml</filePath>
                </attachment>
            </attachments>
            {{#each alerts}}
            <test-case id="{{@index}}" name="{{alert}}" result="Failed" fullname="{{alert}}" time="1">
                <failure>
                    <message>
                          <![CDATA[{{{desc}}}]]>
                    </message>
                    <stack-trace>
                        <![CDATA[ Solution: {{{solution}}} Reference: {{{reference}}}
                            instances:{{#each instances}}
                                * {{uri}} - {{method}} 
                                {{#if evidence}}- {{{evidence}}}{{/if}}
                            {{/each}}
                        ]]>
                    </stack-trace>
                </failure>
            </test-case>
            {{/each}}
        </test-suite>
    </test-run>
   
   {{/each}}
   EOF
```

Run Handlebars

```
handlebars owaspzap/report.json < owaspzap/nunit-template.hbs > owaspzap/report.xml
```

Publish Test Results

```
steps:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: NUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/report.xml'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

So when each step executes in turn
Docker -> as expected

Run ZAP scan -> completes with passes & warnings

2023-10-13T10:14:10.2051037Z ##[section]Finishing: Run ZAP Scan

Install Handlebars

```
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5572261Z ##[section]Starting: Install Handlebars
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5577334Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5577640Z Task         : Bash
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5577730Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5578054Z Version      : 3.229.0
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5578160Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5578337Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-10-13T10:25:01.5578727Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:01.6839367Z Generating script.
2023-10-13T10:25:01.6855434Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-10-13T10:25:01.6865786Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/f63af849-5335-40d3-8f13-4f026b736e26.sh
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2065356Z 
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2091678Z added 8 packages in 907ms
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2103187Z npm notice 
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2104069Z npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.8.1 -> 10.2.0
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2105069Z npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.0>
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2105826Z npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.0` to update!
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2106531Z npm notice
```

Run Handlebars

```
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2467184Z ##[section]Starting: Run Handlebars
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2472295Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2472599Z Task         : Bash
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2472689Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2472996Z Version      : 3.229.0
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2473101Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2473276Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-10-13T10:25:03.2473664Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:03.3631426Z Generating script.
2023-10-13T10:25:03.3648695Z Script contents:
2023-10-13T10:25:03.3650670Z handlebars owaspzap/report.json < owaspzap/nunit-template.hbs > owaspzap/report.xml
2023-10-13T10:25:03.3658036Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-10-13T10:25:03.3676643Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/38b8e342-43ed-4f13-b53e-d1093a7a4906.sh
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4738108Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Handlebars
```

Publish Test Results

```
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4760402Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Test Results
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4765644Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4765943Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4766112Z Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4766394Z Version      : 2.229.1
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4766500Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4766680Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
2023-10-13T10:25:03.4767168Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-13T10:25:03.6101747Z [command]/usr/bin/dotnet --version
2023-10-13T10:25:03.8951150Z 7.0.401
2023-10-13T10:25:05.4385385Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2023-10-13T10:25:05.4752578Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2023-10-13T10:25:05.5280244Z No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/owaspzap/report.xml'.
2023-10-13T10:25:05.5448680Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2023-10-13T10:25:05.8770289Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2023-10-13T10:25:05.8771674Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Test Results
```

And here you can see no results are being found, any ideas please.

Comment: 1) ZAP is no longer part of OWASP. https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2023-08-01-zap-is-joining-the-software-security-project/ 2) It seems the file either isn't being written due to user/permission/storage or that it isn't in the path you think or that the later step has different access (it's there and not read/found).